# Does android phones support CDMA?And do they have an separate MSISDN number?

Tags: android

Does android phones support CDMA? And do they have an separate MSISDN number?

Answer (score 0):

1. support CDMA ?
   Ans. YES
2. seperate MSISDN number?
   Ans. maybe If they are seperate SIM card.